# I can't get DSolve to work on coupled equations

Tags: differential-equations, equation-solving, symbolic, nonlinear

In trying to solve a geodesic equation, I have these coupled equations:

```
eq1 = Derivative[2][u][l] - Cos[u[l]]*Sin[u[l]]*D[v[l], l]*D[v[l], l] == 0; 
eq2 = Derivative[2][v][l] + 2*Cot[u[l]]*D[u[l], l]*D[v[l], l] == 0; 
eq3 = u[0] == 1; 
eq4 = v[0] == 1; 
eq5 = Derivative[1][u][0] == 1; 
eq6 = Derivative[1][v][0] == 1;
```

Now I want a solution for the functions **u**, **v**.  So I try this:

```
DSolve[{eq1, eq2, eq3, eq4, eq5, eq6}, {u, v}, l]
```

And I get:

`DSolve[{-Cos[u[l]] Sin[u[l]] Derivative[1][v][l]^2 + (u^\[Prime]\[Prime])[l] == 0, 2 Cot[u[l]] Derivative[1][u][l] Derivative[1][v][l] + (v^\[Prime]\[Prime])[l] == 0, u[0] == 1, v[0] == 1, Derivative[1][u][0] == 1, Derivative[1][v][0] == 1}, {u, v}, l]`

Which just tells me that Mathematica didn't recognize my input.  What am I doing wrong?

Comment: It may also mean that MMA does not know how to solve your equation / type of equations symbolically. If you change to `NDSolve` and add a range for $l$ a solution can be found, so there is no problem with your formulation.

Comment: You can try using `NDSolve`, however it will only be valid for a certain region that you specify.

Comment: @Yusuf - **NDSolve** does give a proper answer with boundary conditions.  So, naturally, I wanted to know if there was an analytical solution and whether Mathematica had the intelligence to find it.

Comment: @MarcoB - How do I tell if I'm doing something wrong or whether MMa can't solve it?  It'd be great to have some feedback other than my input.

Comment: @Quarkly In general, if using `NDSolve` works but `DSolve` doesn't, and you're using the correct syntax for both, you can assume that Mathematica is unable to find a symbolic solution to the equations.

Comment: @Yusuf - Would you like a list of all the assumptions I've made that have been wrong?

Comment: `Maple` had the intelligence to find it(only general solution).Solution is on 78 pages,transcendental equation,involves indefine integrals,probably no closed-form solution.

Comment: @Quarkly I agree, I also find it unhelpful that Mathematica simply returns the input with no warning here, since similar situations e.g. in `Solve` explicitly report that the system cannot be solved with the methods available. Yusuf’s suggestion is the best I have as well: if the same system can be solved numerically, then it’s probably the case that `DSolve` couldn’t solve it analytically. It still says nothing about whether an analytical solution actually exists, but that is a much harder problem, of course.

Comment: Thanks for the thought.  Again, as a newcomer to Mathematica, it's super unhelpful that having the wrong number of parameters gives you the same kind of answer as being right.  I don't know that I'll ever have enough confidence in my math to make the kind of assumption that Yusuf suggests.

Answer (score 3):

`DSolve` often cannot solve differential equations for which symbolic solutions actually do exist.  So, out of curiosity, I attempted to solve these equations and made some progress, obtaining `v'[l]` in terms of `u[l]`, and `u[l]` as an implicit function of `l`.  Here is the calculation.

Obtain `v'[l]`:

```
Equal @@ (DSolve[eq2, u[l], l][[1, 1]]) /. Exp[2 C[1]] -> c
Solve[%, v'[l]][[1, 1]] /. Exp[2 C[1]] -> c
% /. l -> 0 /. (Rule @@@ {eq3, eq6})
Reverse@Simplify[Sin[1]^2 # & /@ %]
svp = %%% /. %
(* v'l] -> Csc[u[l]]^2 Sin[1]^2 *)
```

Next obtain a first integral for `u[l]`.

```
Equal @@ (Solve[eq1 /. svp, u''[l]][[1, 1]])
(* (u''[l] == Cot[u[l]] Csc[u[l]]^2 Sin[1]^4 *)
u'[l]^2 == 2 Integrate[%[[2]], u[l]] + c
Solve[FullSimplify[% /. l -> 0 /. (Rule @@@ {eq3, eq5})], c][[1]]
Equal @@ (Solve[Simplify[%% /. %], u'[l]][[2, 1]])
(* u'[l] == Sqrt[1 + Sin[1]^2 - Csc[u[l]]^2 Sin[1]^4] *)
```

There is, of course, a second solution with the right side of the equation negative.  Finally, solve the last equation to obtain

```
(# - c) & /@ FullSimplify[Integrate[1/%[[2]], u[l]] == l + c, u {l} > 0]
Solve[FullSimplify[% /. l -> 0 /. (Rule @@ eq3)], c][[1]]
sp = %% /. %
(* l == ArcTan[Sqrt[1/2 (3 - Cos[2])] Cot[1]] Sqrt[(1 - Cos[2])/(3 - Cos[2])] Csc[1] 
   - (4 ArcTan[(2 Cos[u[l]])/Sqrt[4 + 8/(-3 + Cos[2]) + 2 Cos[2] - 2 Cos[2 u[l]]]] 
   Sqrt[2 + 4/(-3 + Cos[2]) + Cos[2] - Cos[2 u[l]]] 
   Sqrt[3 - Cos[2] - 2 Csc[u[l]]^2 Sin[1]^4] Sin[u[l]])/
   (3 + 2 Cos[2] - Cos[4] + 2 (-3 + Cos[2]) Cos[2 u[l]]) *)
```

which is the desired solution for `u[l]` with `u'[l] > 0`, though implicit. The solution for `u'[l] < 0` is obtained similarly.

For comparision, the numerical solution for `u[l]` and `v'[l]` is

```
NDSolveValue[{eq1, eq2, eq3, eq4, eq5, eq6}, {u[l], v'[l]}, {l, -2, 8}];
Plot[{Evaluate@%, Sin[1]^2 Csc[First[%]]^2}, {l, -2, 8}, ImageSize -> Large, 
    AxesLabel -> {"u,v'", l}, LabelStyle -> {15, Bold, Black}]
```

[image]

The analytical solutions compare well with this.  In summary, it is possible to obtain symbolic solutions for these equations with Mathematica, although the solution for `u[l]` is implicit.  All things considered, it seems understandable that `DSolve` could not provide a viable solution for the equations, although showing relevant intermediate results would have been helpful.